# Misunderstood or Wrong Logic for Async and await in C# using ADO Code

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, ado

I have a web api controller get action that is inserting data in database code is as

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string UserName, string Password)
    {

        SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("@UserId", UserName), new SqlParameter("@Password", Password) };
        AdoHelper DBHelper = new AdoHelper();
        Company c = new Company();

        await DBHelper.ExecDataSetProcAsync("[dbo].[usp_Insertuser]", parameters).ContinueWith(Task =>
        {

            DataSet ds = Task.Result;
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count == 1)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 1)
                {
                }
            }
            ds.Dispose();
            Task.Dispose();
        });

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("ok", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
        };
        return response;
    }
```

Where as my AdoHelper methos is as

```
public async Task<DataSet> ExecDataSetProcAsync(string qry, params object[] args)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        return await Task<DataSet>.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(DBConnection.GetConnectionString())
                {
                    AsynchronousProcessing = true
                };
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(qry, CommandType.StoredProcedure, args))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (!reader.IsClosed)
                            ds.Tables.Add().Load(reader);

                        cmd.Connection.Close();
                        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
                        cmd.Dispose();
                    }

                    if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                    }

                }

                return ds;
            });

    }
```

now i am calling this web api controller method and want to insert Data of 10,000 users in loop but it opens 147 Connection with database and then threads start sending 500 internal server error i think Async and Await task are not closing Database Connection properly. Kindly advice what went wrong with my implementation or if i have misunderstood this Async and await in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a new task instead use the Async methods that ADO expose.

Also, instead of disposing the connections manually, wrap everything in using statements

```
public async Task<DataSet> ExecDataSetProcAsync(string qry, params object[] args)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(DBConnection.GetConnectionString())
    {
        AsynchronousProcessing = true
    };
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        using (var cmd = CreateCommand(qry, CommandType.StoredProcedure, args))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            using(var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        ds.Tables.Add().Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ds;  
}
```

Comment: issue is with the connection that never gets closed and then as per your code implementation `Task.Result` gives empty dataset. Thanks for your reply, it decresed execution time of overall api

Comment: @NaveedYousaf does the code "ds.Tables.Add().Load(reader);" add the data to the dataset? if not, change that part